# How do you stop 3 month old kittens from nursing

Tags: behavior

How do I get mother to stop nursing 3 month old kittens?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you feel that you need to?
The kittens will either get bored with it and forget - and the behavior will slowly taper off, or the mother will get tired of the nuisance and push them away.
As long as there's no obvious harm (raw or irritated nipples) there isn't really any need for you to interfere.